# Why F5 does not start a unit test in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a solution with several projects and all of them are unit test projects. While I can start some tests selecting the project as the startup project and pressing F5 there are other projects that when selected as startup and pressed F5 says that a project with an ouput type of class library can not started.

I've compared the projects and all looks the same with the same project properties. Any hint about this?

Thanks in advance mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the project was created to be tested with NUnit and thus was created as a "New class library" instead of a "New test project". This must be writing something at the project file that specifies how to behave when pressing F5.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of your projects that start when you press F5.  I'm guessing that some of your projects have have a start action specified in the debug tab (specifically Start external program) that runs something like the NUnit test runner and passes your class library to it.